# How to specify row and column names in a crosstable when both are categorical

Tags: r, crosstab

I have two categorical variables and I am trying to create a cross tabulation for them. Since both values are yes and no , I want to specify the row and column names for ease of understanding.

```
T4 <- table(bank$Term_deposit, bank$housing_loan) 
%>% prop.table(margin = 2) *100

T4

           no       yes
  no  83.418772 92.217126 <br/>
  yes 16.581228  7.782874
```

```
kable(T4, caption = "%agewise comparison for marital status")
```

```
|    |       no|       yes|<br/>
|:---|--------:|---------:|<br/>
|no  | 83.41877| 92.217126|<br/>
|yes | 16.58123|  7.782874|<br/>
```

Expected output:

```
|    |       no|       yes|<br/>
|:---|--------:|---------:|<br/>
CAT1 | 83.41877| 92.217126|<br/>
|CAT2| 16.58123|  7.782874|
```

OR

```
|    |     cat1|      cat2|<br/>
|:---|--------:|---------:|<br/>
CAT1 | 83.41877| 92.217126|<br/>
|CAT2| 16.58123|  7.782874|<br/>
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do with it in the end, but if the goal is to render a markdown, then consider using  pandoc.table, as it provides a functionality similar to knitr::kable:

```
library(pandoc)

colnames(T4) <- c("CAT1", "CAT2")
rownames(T4) <- c("no", "yes")
pandoc.table(T4)
```

Output:

```
-------------------------
 &nbsp;    CAT1    CAT2  
-------- -------- -------
 **y**    13473    77311 

 **n**    226221     0   
-------------------------
```

Or maybe:

```
colnames(T4) <- c("deposit: no", "deposit: yes")
rownames(T4) <- c("loan: no", "loan: yes")
pandoc.table(T4)
```

Output:

```
--------------------------------------------
    &nbsp;       deposit: no   deposit: yes 
--------------- ------------- --------------
 **loan: no**       13473         77311     

 **loan: yes**     226221           0       
--------------------------------------------
```

Another possibility would be to use the expss package:

```
library(expss)

df <- apply_labels(bank,
                   Term_deposit= "Term deposit",
                   housing_loan= "Housing loan")

cro_cpct(bank$Term_deposit, bank$housing_loan)
```

Output:

```
 |              |              | Housing loan |     |
 |              |              |            0 |   1 |
 | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | --- |
 | Term deposit |            0 |         39.4 | 100 |
 |              |            1 |         60.6 |     |
 |              | #Total cases |         66.0 |  34 |
```

Both packages also provide several other functionalities to make neat tables, it is worth taking a look.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I was trying to avoid that extra line of code ( row names() or colnames() ).  I was looking if any function can take the row or col names as param for e.g. cross tab(bank$Term_deposit, bank$personal_loan, rownames = c("TD:Yes","TD_no) ) .